# Special usage of `const`

Tags: c, constants

I have learned (correct me if I am wrong) much about the keyword `const` and I learned that it is very easy if you read it from the right to the left like this:

```
int a = 0;                 // `a` is an integer. Its value is initialized with zero
const int b = 0;           // `b` is an integer which is constant. Its value is set to zero
int * c = &a;              // `c` is a pointer to an int. `c` is pointing to `a`.
int * const d= &a;         // `d` is a constant pointer to an int. It is pointing to `a`.
const int * e = &a;        // `e` is a pointer to an int which is constant. It is pointing to `a`.
int * const f = &a;        // `f` is a constant pointer to an int. It is pointing to `a`.
const int * const g = &b;  // `g` is a constant pointer to a constant integer. It is pointing to `b`.
```

But what is about this:

```
int const * h;
```

Is `h` a pointer to a constant int? If yes, what is the different to `e`?

And what is about this:

```
int const i;
```

Is `i` this the same type as `b`?

Comment: `const int` and `int const` are the same. For your pointer example it only matters whether the `const` is before or after the `*`.

Comment: As explained in the accepted answer to the duplicate, the initial `const` can be placed on either side of the type name.

Comment: https://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 2):

The `const` qualifier can be freely placed before or after a type keyword as long as there are no `*` symbols between them.

So the following are equivalent:

```
int const *h;
const int *h;
```

As are these:

```
int const i;
const int i;
```

But these are not:

```
int * const p;
const int *p;
```